# Scale Box2D Circle Shape and it's Collision Detection?

Tags: box2d, collision-detection, game-physics

If a circle stretches during the phases of launch, and becomes elongated (gaining height and losing width) how to dynamically adjust the collision shape (in Box2D) as it's scaling? Can this be done through each frame of all the steps to full stretch and back to a circle shape?

Similarly, when bouncing, it squashes out a little, and needs to detect more width and less height.

[image]

Imagine this is a Hero character in a game, and he's a bit of a jumper, even able to do midair 'double jumps'. But most of the elongation and squishing happens during ground interactions. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Hello, please notice that implementation of solution for this can differ in different game engines - if you are using any specific technology (like Unity, pyGame, libGDX...) update your tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have two parts of the issue:

1. **Changing fixture shape dynamically**

   Box2D supports various types of shapes like:

   - *CircleShape* (simple)
   - *PolygonShape* (simple)
   - *ChainShape*, *EdgeShape* (complex)

   The situation here depends on what type of shape you need here. If "simple" type of shape is enough the solution is very easy and it will be (for [PolygonShape](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/PolygonShape.html)) something like

   ```
   //! I'm using LibGDX in code examples but you can translate it to other engines

   Body body;

   ...

   //assuming that body has one fixture - if not just keep it's reference and call it directly
   ((PolygonShape) body.getFixtureList().first().getShape() ).setAsBox(hx, hy);
   ```

   *notice here that for [CircleShape](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/CircleShape.html) you do not even need to cast it because [Shape](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Shape.html) class contains `setRadius` method*

   If you need "complex" type of shape the situation is more complicated but still kind of easy. The way you handle it is to **destroy current fixture and recreate it with another shape** like

   ```
   Body body;
   FixtureDef fixtureDef;

   ...

   //creating fixturDef - for further usage (setting friction, density etc...)

   ...

   //again assuming that body has one fixture - but also can keep reference
   body.destroyFixture( bb1.getFixtureList().first() );

   ChainShape shape = new ChainShape();
   //creating shape...

   fixtureDef.shape = shape;

   body.createFixture(fixtureDef);

   //you must dispose shape after fixture creating!
   shape.dispose();
   ```
2. **Creating ellipse**

   Although Box2D supports various kinds of shapes **there's no ellipse type** and you need to use some technique to generate it on our own. In the internet there are many ways described - I will show you how to generate ellipse as `ChainShape` instance.

   I will be using [parametric equation for ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Parametric_form_in_canonical_position) with `0 <= t < 2π` (in radians). The method looks like:

   ```
   //overriding method to handle default STEPS value
   ChainShape createEllipse(float width, float height)
   {
       return createEllipse(width, height, 64);
   }

   ChainShape createEllipse(float width, float height, int STEPS)
   {
       ChainShape ellipse = new ChainShape();      
       Vector2[] verts = new Vector2[STEPS];

       for(int i = 0; i < STEPS; i++)
       {
           float t = (float)(i*2*Math.PI)/STEPS;
           verts[i] = new Vector2(width * (float)Math.cos(t), height * (float)Math.sin(t));
       }

       ellipse.createLoop(verts);
       return ellipse;
   }
   ```

   where:

   - *width* - width of the ellipse
   - *height* - height of the ellipse
   - *STEPS* - count of points that creating ellipse (bigger STEPS = smoother ellipse but more expensive to generate)

   So to sum up - **assuming that you know what size of body is during simulation** (because if you do not know it is big topic bigger than this question) the scenario would be:

   - check if I should change fixture (*has body's size changed?*)
   - if **yes**:

     - destroy old fixture
     - generate new shape with new size
     - create new fixture
     - dispose created shape

   in a code it would be something like:

   ```
   //in render method
   if( bodySizeChanged() ) //this method is checking somehow if you should change fixture
   {
       //again assuming that body has one fixture - but also can keep reference           
       body.destroyFixture( body.getFixtureList().first() );

       ChainShape ellipse = createEllipse(newWidth, newHeight);
       fixtureDef.shape = ellipse;

       body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
       ellipse.dispose();
   }
   ```

   Of course creating new shape every time is not very efficient and better way would be to create some collection of shapes `Array<ChainShape>` or even `FixtureDef` on loading (e.g. in `show()` method) and just get the desired *shape/fixtureDef* during render method.

---

**EDIT** - for example if you have a collection of sprites for your animation you can generate another collection of shapes for each of them - *but only if previous animation frame has another size* to not to change shape to the same shape - it would be something like:

```
    Sprite[] frames = new Sprite[N]; //N sprites for animation
    ChainShape[] shapes = new ChainShape[N]; //N shapes

    ...

    Vector2 lastSize = new Vector2(0,0); //or another initial value - depends on what sizes your sprites have

    for(int i = 0; i < frames.length; i++)
    {
        Sprite s = frames[i];

        if(lastSize.x != s.getWidth() || lastSize.y != s.getHeight())
        {
            shapes[i] = createEllipse(s.getWidth(), s.getHeight());
            lastSize.set(s.getWidth(), s.getHeight());
        }
        else
        {
            shapes[i] = null;
        }
    }
```

and then in the render method

```
    //render method
    int index = getCurrentAnimationFrameIndex(animation); //some function to get index of current sprite of character

    if(shapes[index] != null)
        //change fixture
```

Of course you should remember to **dispose all not-null shapes** at the end of your application (at least if it is Libgdx)!

---

One interesting thing more that I have discovered here is that `ChainShape` **is not rotating during collision** what was a kind of weird for me. Actually it could be good for you (I guess that the ball is some kind of character and it should not has a rotation - maybe you will even set some `setFixedRotation` on its body) but if you want the body to rotate the way to do it is to define `MassData` with *I* (inertia) set to some value and then attach this `MassData` to body

```
    MassData m = new MassData();

    m.center.set(0, 0);
    m.I = 100; //example value
    body.setMassData(m);
```

Unfortunately I cannot tell you what exactly value should be set there but you can read more on [Wikipedia site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia).

Comment: "Of course creating new shape every time is not very efficient and better way would be to create some collection of shapes Array<ChainShape>"  ...so you're suggesting to create a "spriteSheet-like" group of shape possibilities, and have them all loaded and ready to use, and swap in the appropriate shape for each frame where there's distortion of the character? // added an animation to the question to show the "hero" jumping.

Comment: Yup - something like this. Check out my last edit - I tried to describe how I see it